# Why is this named function not allowed to be passed as a Func<> argument in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, casting, delegates

I am having trouble understanding what the rules are for passing delegates in C#3.0.  The final `.Max()` is giving the compile error as shown below, but I can't understand what the significant difference is between that case and any of the others.

```
int NamedIdentity(int val) { return val; }
Func<int, int> Identity = x => x;

void Main() {
    var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

    range.Max();
    range.Max(x => x);
    range.Max(Identity);
    range.Max((Func<int, int>) NamedIdentity);
    range.Max(new Func<int, int>(NamedIdentity));

    // this line gives compile error
    range.Max(NamedIdentity); 
    /* The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
    * 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Max<int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>, System.Func<int,decimal>)' and 
    * 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Max<int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>, System.Func<int,decimal?>)'
    */
}
```

Why does this not compile?  My understanding is that `NamedIdentity` is declared as a `Func<int, int>`, so it does not need to be casted, although obviously I'm wrong.  One clue is that the compile error is talking about `Decimal`s even though none are referenced anywhere in the code.  Where did that come from?  Can a function reference not be implicitly cast to a delegate of the same signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The C# 3.0 compiler will not implicitly cast a method group to a delegate when resolving generic parameters.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112002618/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx)
This was fixed in C# 4.0.

Comment: @recursive: I believe because those are the first two overloads.  I'm not entirely sure.